# How to Conditionally Format an Excel SmartArt graphic

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm working on a project in Excel 2016, and what needs to be done is a chart (preferably a circle) that changes each "slice's" color based on the score. The score is an integer that is pulled from the excel sheet, so it'll change based on the survey results.

Scores go 1 through 5, where 1 is red and 5 is green. I know how to conditionally format the cell itself to be the color I need, but I don't know how to do so on a chart.

I looked into VBA (via a YouTube video), but I can't get that to work either.

Here is the code I have for VBA, if anyone could help me out, or let me know how to do it at all, that would be great!

```
Private Sub SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim s As String

Dim mySeries As Series

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    For Each mySeries In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        If mySeries.ChartType <> xlPie Then GoTo SkipNotPie

        s = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")(2)
        vntValues = mySeries.Values

        For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
            mySeries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).Interiror.Color
        Next i

SkipNotPie:
    Next mySeries
Next cht

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this just a typo? `Interior.color`, not `Interiror`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistyping

Range(s).Cells(i).Interiror.Color

and sub procedure variable is not used in your code.

```
Sub test()
    SheetActivate Activesheet '<~~ This will execute the following procedure.

End Sub

Private Sub SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim s As String

Dim mySeries As Series

For Each cht In Sh.ChartObjects
    For Each mySeries In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        If mySeries.ChartType <> xlPie Then GoTo SkipNotPie

        s = Split(mySeries.Formula, ",")(2)
        vntValues = mySeries.Values

        For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
            mySeries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).Interior.Color
        Next i

SkipNotPie:
    Next mySeries
Next cht

End Sub
```

[image]

If your cell color is conditionally formated then change like this

```
For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
    'mySeries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).Interior.Color
    mySeries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
Next i
```